# Is there a benefit using PACKET_MMAP? (Linux)

Tags: linux, network-programming, udp, network-protocols

I'm struggeling with why I should try the multi packet send PACKET_MMAP method.

I got a data mass of around 3 milion bytes every 20ms that i'm going to send over a 10gbps interface.

I need to process all data in an packet so the data is going to be in the cache then I just send it the 'normal' way (sendto). in this case the move to kernel would be from cache so thats one memory transfer.

Since I need to process all data in the packet using PACKET_MMAP would also be one move of the data from userspace to userspace then DMA from userspace. So would PACKET_MMAP gain me anything? my guess is that it would not since both methods will move the data once and even thoug it looks like two times in the (sendto) case since the data will reside in the cache it will effectivly be only once..

Am I wrong?

Thanks for any help.

/Anders.

Comment: Is that a typo on your question `one move of the data from userspace to userspace then DMA from userspace` ? With PACKET_MMAP packets aren't DMA's from userspace (for Tx), they are copied into an `sk_buff` in Kernel memory then DMA'ed from there. I need to check receive but I think it's the same.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I thought the whole idea with PACKET_MMAP was to avoid moving data into kernel space when sending.

Comment: DMA can only happen from Kernel space (well separate space is allocated by the Kernel for DMA) - you can't DMA from user-land to the NIC (like in the way DPDK works) without disconnecting the NIC from the Kernel (as DPDK does, for example). Yeah I know what you mean, I thought `PACKET_MMAP` would give zero copy forwarding but the packets in the Tx ring are in fact `memcpy()`'ed into `sk_buff`s in the Kernel as I found out by reading through the code: https://github.com/jwbensley/EtherateMT/wiki/Linux-Kernel-socket()-&-sendto()-References and the `sk_buff`s are then DMA'ed to the NIC.

Comment: Oops! Wrong link: https://github.com/jwbensley/EtherateMT/wiki/Linux-Kernel-tracing-for-sendto()-using-AF_PACKET,-PACKET_MMAP-and-PACKET_FANOUT